# Simple toggle query

Tags: jquery

Look at this sample code:

```
<a class="change" href="#" id="swap01"><img src="off.gif"></a></div>
<a class="change" href="#" id="swap02"><img src="off.gif"></a></div>
<a class="change" href="#" id="swap03"><img src="off.gif"></a></div>

<form>
<input type="hidden" name="field01" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="field02" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="field03" value="0" />
</form>
```

What I want to happen is that, for example, if I click on the image link within **swap02**:

1) The image source for that link changes from **off.gif** to **on.gif**
2) The corresponding hidden field in the form (**field02**) changes from **0** to **1**.

When I click the same link again, it reverts back to **off.gif** and **0**.

Just three are given as an example, but this needs to be scalable (up to 99 items).

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: It is, yes; but what have ***you*** tried to do, what went wrong?

Comment: I have a ridiculously long piece of manual JavaScript code to perform this. It works, but it's hardcoded (one line for each instance) and it's unwiedly. Was just looking for someone to help me condense it down to a one or two liner using jQuery. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
$("a[id^='swap']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $img = $("img",this);
    $img.attr("src") == 'off.gif' ? $img.attr("src","on.gif") : $img.attr("src","off.gif");
    var $hf = $("input[name='field" + this.id.replace('swap','') + "']");
    $hf.val() == '1' ? $hf.val('0') : $hf.val('1');
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/dwE78/

Comment: Thanks, this nails it for me (apart from a tiny bug where the src of the img was not being referenced correctly, which I rectified with "find('img')". :)

Comment: @RC - Thanks for pointing that out - I've updated the code sample to include a fix. Please upvote or accept the answer if you think helped. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
var i,$h
$('a img').click(
    function(){
        i = $(this).index('a img');
        $h = $('input:hidden').eq(i);

        if ($h.val() == 0){
            this.src = 'on.gif';
            $h.val(1);
        }
        else {
            this.src = 'off.gif';
            $h.val(0);
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/E5sBy/1/).

Amended the code, to change the `src` as well. I forgot about that part in the first instance...

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad to have been of help. Note that I've just edited the answer a little, to account for the changes of the image's `src` attribute.

Comment: There are couple of things I object to in this response, though they are kinda given by the OP question. Look ups by index are kinda bad. I would've at least used matching ID portion. Using `img.src` is also pretty cheap and hacky.

Comment: What's 'hacky' about using `this.src`?

Comment: Yes, agree, so implemented ipr101's method below with no indexing. img.src is not ideal, but I am needing to work with CSS backgrounds as well (not given in example above), so it's the easiest way forward.

Comment: @DavidThomas separation of presentation from logic (or rather lack of it). Ideally js code should know nothing about image name/location. Adding/removing classes is the kosher way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This will loop through all the images and apply a click event which will toggle the image and set the value to the relevant val based on the image' current src.

```
  for(var I=1;I<99;I++){
        $('swap'+(I.toString().length == 1 ? '0' : '') + I).click(function(){
             var on = 0;
              if($(this).attr('src') == 'on.gif'){
                    on = 1;
                    $(this).attr('src','off.gif');
               }else{
                     $(this).attr('src','on.gif');
                }
                $('field'+(I.toString().length == 1 ? '0' : '') + I).val(I.toString());
          });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/jeSqt/) is how I would've done this.

A few notes:

1. I am using `<div>`s becuase it is a bad taste to use anchors for
   purely client side operations. This tends to cause issues in IE with
   window unload events.
2. I moved form on around the your toggles because it seems they should
   be bundled together. If for whatever reason you cannot use that,
   then you have to parse out the id number from the div, then look up
   the input.
3. Using classes instead of changing element properties.

===========================================================================

Edit: About divs and backgrounds...
If you are looking to build a custom button-like control, then you should stick with divs. Why? Because div is the most basic and lightweight building block you can get. It doesn't come with some weirdo predefined (and browser inconsistent) appearance and behavior rules, which you most likely don't need and shouldn't have to worry about.

For instance sometimes `<img src="..." />` will display without a border, and sometimes you need to give it `border=0`. The only reason to use img tag ever is if you want to stretch your image. Major advantages in using div with background image:

1. It can be operated from js via class names, which is cleaner code.
2. It can be used with image sprites (as in my example)
3. It wont suddenly appear 2 pixels lower for no
   good reason in a new version of IE.

Same thing with anchor tags. People use them because they used to idea `<a href="...">...</a>` being *the clickable thing*, but it actually comes with whole bunch of behavior you don't want. And the whole "clickable" is super easy to emulate with just `cursor:pointer;` CSS. I in fact have a staple `.clickable {cursor:pointer;}` declared in my CSS files (much like `.hidden {display:none;}`). The awesomeness of this approach is that it can be used to control both appearance and logic at the same time like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/rKJKE/)

Long story short, if you are building custom controls, always stick with `div`s. They are simple to define, consistent, lightweight and easy to work with from js code. More to your question: If you need an image over another image, just make it 2 divs with background images.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I will take on board note number (1) above and make the necessary amendments. (2) above is possible, but my code is cleaner if separated. (3) I can't use, because I am already assigning a background CSS property that remains unique and fixed for each item (stripped out from example code for simplification purposes). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RC Is your background also an image or just a color? You can combine image and background color on the same element. http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/jeSqt/2/

Comment: I need an image on an image, hence <img> on a css-background img.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    $('body').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();  
        var $this = $(this);
        var $img = $('img', $this);
        var $hidden = $('input[name$="' + $this.attr('id').slice(-2) + '"]');

        // toggle img src
        $img.attr('src', function(i, attr) {
            return (attr == 'on.gif') ? 'off.gif' : 'on.gif';
        });

        // change hidden value
        $hidden.val(function(i, attr) {
            return (attr == '0') ? 1 : 0;
        });
    })

});
```

Change the delegate target selector (in my example, 'a' elements within 'body') according to your needs.

**EDIT**

Using delegate is preferred when there are likely to be many event handlers on a page. 99 isn't a huge number, but it is probably enough to start worrying about performance.